# sharepoint online 2013 how to handle list view threshold

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have a list with 25000 items. The items can be seen in a view where there are no grouping/filtering. But if any of the filtering/grouping is done, the view breaks.  All I need to do is group the items based on a column(This column is indexed). We don't want to split the list or increase the threshold. Any thoughts how this can be done?

Answer (score 2):

1) After filtering does the view exceed 5000 items?

> You also need to make sure that the first column of the filter does
>   not return more items than the List View Threshold, even if the final
>   result of the filtered view returns less than the List View Threshold.

From: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-lists-and-libraries-with-many-items-1f4985e4-6d67-4e0c-a473-ea17e7058585?redir=0&CorrelationId=3bef4740-61d5-485e-ae8e-a92f7c55de80&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

2) Are there any items in the recycle bin?

> If you are filtering a list by an indexed field, check your recycle
>   bin for deleted items. Items in the recycle bin aren't actually
>   deleted from the backend database until they are removed from the
>   recycle bin. If the total number of filtered items in the list and in
>   the recycle bin is greater than the List Threshold limit, then you may
>   get an incomplete set of results, or none at all.

Bear in mind that even IF you decide to increase the threshold, [increasing threshold is not an option in SharePoint Online](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Online-and-OneDrive-for-Business-software-boundaries-and-limits-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498).